# Android Viewgroup Issues

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

I have an issue using a `viewGroup`, for some reason the `id` doesn't process the statement, and really I tried everything, can you help please?

I don't know if it is something about the `version3.3.2` or what's wrong with the code

```
public class popularAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<popularAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<popular> mPopulars;

    public popularAdapter (Context context,List<popular>populars){

        mContext=context;
        mPopulars=populars;



    }




    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                                      //HERE IS THE ISSUE
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.popular_item2,viewGroup,false);

        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    popular popularCur=mPopulars.get(position);
    ImageViewHolder.prodName.setText(popularCur.getProduc_name());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView prd_name;
        public TextView prd_price;
        public TextView prd_img;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            prd_name =itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodName);
            prd_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodPrice);
            prd_img  =itemView.findViewById(R.id.prodImageHolder);




        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the context you are sending.See my answer down there.Try that solution.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta sir not in here context check he returning 0 in item count

Comment: yeah nice point @Ashvinsolanki

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

problem is here

you will never get any items in **`RecyclerView`** because you are returning 0 in `getItemCount`

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() 
    {
       //return 0 ?
        return 0;
    }
```

change with

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() 
    {
        return mPopulars.size();
    }
```

### [**`getItemCount`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount())

```
int getItemCount ()
```

Returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popular_item2,viewGroup,false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing @Ashwin solanki answer

Change following code

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() 
{
   //return 0 ?
    return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() 
{
   //return 0 ?
    if(mPopulars != null) {
        return mPopulars.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Description: onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder methods get called for the count which is returned by getItemCount method. As your code is always returning 0, these methods will not get called and list will not get populated on UI.

Also, check following line from you code from onBindViewHolder method:

```
ImageViewHolder.prodName.setText(popularCur.getProduc_name());
```

You are considering 'prodName' variable of 'ImageViewHolder' class as static but it is not. Instead it should be

```
holder.prodName.setText(popularCur.getProduc_name());
```